# Ember.js - Nested resources Template Error: "Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object"

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

[My Code - JSbin](http://jsbin.com/axaqix/10/edit)

I wanted to add a resource (e.g. `sites/5/posts/` -> posts is the new resources I added).

```
WebApp.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('sites', { path: '/' } , function() {
        this.resource('site', { path: '/sites/:site_id'} ,  function() {
            this.resource('posts', { path: 'posts'

            }); //posts

        }); //sites/id 

        this.route('new', {path: 'new'});

    });

});
```

My template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sites">
<ul>
    {{#each site in controller}}
    <li>
        {{#linkTo 'site' this}} {{site.siteName}} {{/linkTo}}
        {{#linkTo 'posts'}} > {{/linkTo}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}

</ul>
{{#linkTo 'sites.new'}} ADD NEW WEBSITE {{/linkTo}}

{{outlet}}
```

I want to each list item to have the link that points `sites/:site_id/posts/`.
Adding the line `{{#linkTo 'posts'}} > {{/linkTo}}` to the template generates the error:
`Assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object.`

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few changes:

1. You shouldn't set the `id` attribute on your models, so I removed the `id: DS.attr('integer')` lines from your Site and Post models.
2. The line causing the problem is your second linkTo helper:

   {{#linkTo 'posts'}} > {{/linkTo}}

   The `posts` route (actually `posts.index`, which Ember autogenerates) expects a `site` object because it's nested under the `site` resource. The path you're trying to link to is `sites/:site_id/posts/`, so you need to provide the a site, otherwise it doesn't know which site's posts to display.

So you're getting an "cannot call id on undefined object" that prevents the template from rendering, I assume, because the template's linkTo helper tries to create a link with an id, but it has no object to serialize.

**In short, all you to do is add back the argument to the linkTo helper: `{{#linkTo 'posts' site}}`**. See here: http://jsbin.com/axaqix/13/edit